# Ferramentas de string em ruby

Tags: array, string, ruby, split

Suponha a seguinte `string`: `"acc5???7???7ss?3rr1???5"`.

Como verificar se os três pontos de interrogação existem (exatamente três) e se estão antes ou depois de números que somados dão mais que 10?

Pensei em usar split nos `???`, mas me perco a partir daí.

```
teste = "acc5???7???7ss?3rr1??5"

clean = "???"


var = teste.split(clean)
puts "#{var}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar o método `scan`, passando uma expressão regular (regex):

```
teste = "acc5???7???7ss?3rr1??5"
var = teste.scan(/(?<=\?{3})\d+|\d+(?=\?{3})/).map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)

puts "#{var}" # 19
if var > 10
    puts "valor maior que 10"
else
    puts "valor menor ou igual a 10"
end
```

A regex é `(?<=\?{3})\d+|\d+(?=\?{3})` (as barras no início e fim servem apenas para delimitar a regex, mas não fazem parte da mesma). Explicando:

Ela usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`), que significa "ou". Isso quer dizer que a regex tem 2 possibilidades.

A primeira é `(?<=\?{3})\d+`:

- `\d+` corresponde a "um ou mais dígitos"
- o trecho dentro de `(?<= ... )` é um [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html); ele serve para verificar se algo existe antes da posição atual. No caso, esse "algo" é `\?{3}` (exatamente 3 ocorrências do ponto de interrogação)

Ou seja, este trecho procura por um ou mais dígitos, desde que tenham 3 pontos de interrogação imediatamente antes.

A segunda possibilidade é `\d+(?=\?{3})`, e é similar à primeira. Temos um ou mais dígitos (`\d+`), e agora temos um *lookahead*, que verifica se algo existe à frente (e no caso, o "algo" também é "3 pontos de interrogação").

Ou seja, a regex pega um ou mais dígitos, mas só se tiver os 3 pontos de interrogação antes ou depois.

O método `scan` retorna um array com os dígitos capturados. Mas regex só trabalha com texto, então esses dígitos (no caso, o 5 e os números 7) são retornados como strings.

Então eu uso `map` para transformá-los em números (através de `to_i`), e depois uso `reduce` para somá-los. Depois basta ver se o resultado é maior que 10.

---

#### Atenção

A regex acima também pega os números que tenham mais que 3 pontos de interrogação antes ou depois ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/dp0uvw/2/)). Se quiser exatamente 3, tem que incrementar um pouco mais a regex:

```
var = teste.scan(/(?<=[^\?]\?{3})\d+|\d+(?=\?{3}(?:[^\?]|$))/).map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

Eu acrescentei `[^\?]`, que é "qualquer caractere que não seja o `?`", assim ele não pega os dígitos, caso haja mais que 3 pontos de interrogação antes ou depois ([veja a diferença](https://regex101.com/r/dp0uvw/4/)).

Comment: Excelente resolução, regex é realmente uma ferramente poderosa. Preciso praticar mais. Agradeço!